# How to work with JSON object in React

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose, reactjs

So here is the set up:

I have simple nodejs backend (based on express and mongoose), which responds to GET request with some JSON (in the form of Object of objects).

So after I get the response, I want to render a component, for each elements of said Object of objects. If it was array, I could simply use array.map(), and render a component in the callback function. But since what I have, is Object, i can not use that.

So... Should I return and Array from the backend. If so how do I tell mongoose to return the result of model.find() in the form of array.

Or should I convert the object to array in the frontend? In this case, how would I do it without putting it through a loop of some sort?

Lastly, I tried to make it work like so:

```
render: function() {
    //console.log('render TodoList componenr');
    var items = this.state.todoItems;
    return(
        <ul>
            {for (var item in items){
                console.log(item);
            }}
        </ul>
        ); 
}
```

To which i get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (30:9)
  28 |                  return(
  29 |                      <ul>
> 30 |                              {for (var item in items){
     |          ^
  31 |                                  
  32 |                              }}
  33 |                      </ul>
```

Which is super weird, as it points to empty location?

Any ideas how  could make this work?

Comment: by the way, that loop works perfect just above the return statement.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over an object you could use Object.keys like so:

```
Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key) {
    return renderItem(yourObject[key]);
});
```

The method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

It's supported by IE >= 9, Chrome >= 5, Safari >= 5, Firefox >= 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can setting the object.map function equal to a variable outside the return function and then just return that variable.

```
render() {

    var article = this.props.article;


    var articleNodes = article.map(function(article, key){
            if(article.iurl == ""){
                article.iurl = "basketball.jpg";
            };

            return(
            <li key={key}>
                <Image item={article}/>
                <div className="post-basic-info">
                    <h3><a target="_blank" href={article.url}>{article.title}</a></h3>
                    <span><a href="#"><label> </label>{article.team}</a></span>
                    <p>{article.description}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            )
        });

    return(
            <div>
                {articleNodes}
            </div>
        )
}
```